# scipy spline interpolation with interp1d IndexError

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to get started with scipy and can't seem to get the example from [interpolation.interp1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) to work when using a kind other than 'linear' (I tried 'zero' and 'cubic').

I couldn't find someone having the same problem while searching in Google, so I guess it's something stupid on my part.

I use scipy 0.11 on python 2.73 with OSX 10.8

The code not working:

```
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 10)
y = np.exp(-x/3.0)
f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind="zero")
xnew = np.arange(0,9, 0.1)
ynew = f(xnew)   # use interpolation function returned by `interp1d`
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xnew, ynew, '-')
plt.show()
```

---

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-23bb96a1589b> in <module>()
  4 f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind="zero")
  5 xnew = np.arange(0,9, 0.1)
----> 6 ynew = f(xnew)   # use interpolation function returned by `interp1d`
  7 plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xnew, ynew, '-')
  8 plt.show()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.pyc in __call__(self, x_new)
394         out_of_bounds = self._check_bounds(x_new)
395 
--> 396         y_new = self._call(x_new)
397 
398         # Rotate the values of y_new back so that they correspond to the

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.pyc in _call_spline(self, x_new)
370     def _call_spline(self, x_new):
371         x_new =np.asarray(x_new)
--> 372         result = spleval(self._spline,x_new.ravel())
373         return result.reshape(x_new.shape+result.shape[1:])
374 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.pyc in spleval((xj, cvals, k), xnew, deriv)
833             res[sl].imag = _fitpack._bspleval(xx,xj,cvals.imag[sl],k,deriv)
834         else:
--> 835             res[sl] = _fitpack._bspleval(xx,xj,cvals[sl],k,deriv)
836     res.shape = oldshape + sh
837     return res

IndexError: too many indices
```

When starting the debug console here i can narrow it down to cvals[sl] causing the error with

```
sl = (slice(None, None, None), 0) # <-- I don't really get the slice part here...
cvals = array([ 1.        ,  0.71653131,  0.51341712,  0.36787944,  0.26359714,
    0.1888756 ,  0.13533528,  0.09697197,  0.06948345])
```

Can someone reproduce this or is something wrong on my machine?

Comment: Try running the code as a script, instead of from your python interpreter. If that works, try quitting/restarting your interpreter.

Comment: I just tried that. I edited the code above to be executable as a script. The result is the same on my system.

Comment: In your debug console, try printing `cvals.shape`. It should be `(9,)`. For some reason, it appears yours is `(9,0)`, because `sl` is getting an errant `0` on the end of the tuple. `sl` should be `(slice(None, None, None),)`.

Comment: Well sl has the index appended from line 830: sl = (slice(None),)+index
Debug console states:
ipdb> cvals.shape
(9,)

Comment: sh seems to be an empty tuple: ipdb> sh
()

Comment: What does `res.shape` and `list(np.ndindex(*sh))` return?

Comment: ipdb> res.shape
(90,) 

ipdb> list(np.ndindex(*sh))
*** Error in argument: u'(np.ndindex(*sh))' (I guess this is because sh is an empty tuple?)

Comment: That's really odd. I have no idea why `list(np.ndindex(*sh))` should raise an exception. On Ubuntu 11.10, Python 2.7.2, scipy 0.9.0,  `list(np.ndindex(*sh))` evaluates to `[()]`.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with ipdb... the following statement works: ipdb> for i in np.ndindex(*sh): print i
elvaluates to: (0,)

Comment: This is the source of the problem. For me, `[i for i in np.ndindex(*())]` is `[()]`, while for you, it is `[(0,)]`. What version of numpy are you using? (Mine is numpy 1.5.1).

Comment: I just checked -- the code for `np.ndindex` is the same for versions 1.5.1 and 1.6.2. The definition for `ndindex` should look like [this](http://ideone.com/MtSlA). If you type `np.ndindex??` at the `ipdb>` prompt, you should see the definition of `np.ndindex` on your machine. Perhaps use `diff` or some `diff-like` tool to check that our definitions are the same?

Comment: There is quite the difference between the definitions, after looking at it in ipython i compared the definition in index_tricks.py. I installed Numpy yesterday. I'll check again if its an official release or the dev version.

Comment: I'm reinstalling numpy and scipy with pip and will check if this solves the problem

Comment: Reinstalling numpy, scipy and matplotlib did the trick, thank you very much for pointing out the source of the problem!

Comment: I think there is/was a known issue with `ndindex` in the numpy dev version, which should be fixed in the release though, so my guess is you actually did install the development or 1.7 beta release by accident.

Comment: @Dirk: now that it's solved, please write an answer to this question that states that you found the problem, and it was fixed by installing a released version of Numpy.

Comment: @pv. I wasn't able to do that (until a few minutes ago) because of reputation limitations ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that while following along an installation instruction for scipy on OSX I installed a non-release version of numpy without realizing it.

Reinstalling numpy, scipy and matplotlib with pip solved the problem.

Many thanks to unutbu for pointing out a the source of the problem.